# Changed iPhone Backup File Type. What to do?

Tags: iphone, windows, backup

I was browsing through File Explorer on my Windows 10 laptop, and I located my iPhone backup files.
I thought that they were my photos, so I converted (just) one of them into a .jpeg.

I can't revert them back as the iPhone backup files just show up as a 'File' on my Windows 10 laptop.

It's not fatal (I can just backup my iPhone again), just wondering if I can convert the file back to the original file type that Apple used for them.
(:

Comment: Did you actually convert them (which I doubt) or just rename their suffix?

Answer (score 1):

The files in the backup are likely HEIC (or AAE for edits made in Photos). Furthermore, the backup could be encrypted, such that the contents of the backup files cannot be read normally.

- You can’t convert a file from one type to another by renaming the extension; if this is what you’ve done, rename it back.
- If you tried to convert the file using some conversion process, it may have corrupted the file. If you overwrite the original, it’s gone.